# R recode a column based on a string value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows

```
date     volume
1-1-90    1.1M
2-1-90     200
3-1-90     0.5M
4-1-90    100
5-1-90     1M
```

The values with M means in millions. I would like to detect the values with letter M or m in them and transform these values into the numerical equivalents

```
date     volume
1-1-90    1100000
2-1-90     200
3-1-90     500000
4-1-90    100
5-1-90    10000000
```

Is there a nifty way of doing it in R?

I have used an ifelse condition as follows

```
(df)[, Volumes := ifelse(volume %in% c("m", "M"),volume * 1000000,0)]
```

but this does not seem to work. Am sure am overlooking which must be trivial.

Comment: It looks lie you have a `data.table` rather than a `data.frame`

Comment: So do you have a `data.table` or a `data.frame`?

Comment: I have a dataframe. I transformed it to a data.table and the syntax I copied from my terminal was for the data.table.

Comment: So why did you accept the `data.frame` solution then? You would never use `df$volume <- ` in `data.table` as it makes an unnecessary copy of the whole `data.table`. You will always use `:=` (like in your example). In this case `df$volume` was created 3(!!) times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you have a `data.table` object there (or maybe you mistakenly using `data.table` syntax on a `data.frame`?)

Anyway, if `df` is a `data.table` object, I would go with

```
df[grepl("m", volume, ignore.case = T), 
   volume2 := as.numeric(gsub("m", "", volume, ignore.case = T)) * 1e6]
df[is.na(volume2), volume2 := as.numeric(as.character(volume))][, volume := NULL]
df
#      date volume2
# 1: 1-1-90 1100000
# 2: 2-1-90     200
# 3: 3-1-90  500000
# 4: 4-1-90     100
# 5: 5-1-90 1000000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> dat$volume <- ifelse( grepl("M|m" ,dat$volume), 
                             1e6*as.numeric(sub("M|m","", dat$volume)), 
                             as.numeric(as.character(dat$volume) ) )
> dat
    date  volume
1 1-1-90 1100000
2 2-1-90     200
3 3-1-90  500000
4 4-1-90     100
5 5-1-90 1000000
```

Comment: I get this warning though: Warning message:
In ifelse(grepl("M|m", dat$volume), 1e+06 * as.numeric(sub("M|m",  :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: That would not necessarily be a bad result. If you post the output of dput() on your data-object, then the ambiguities of class and format in objects will not be a problem. (I had tested my code on what I imagined was the object.)

Answer (score 0):

The `stringr` package can also work here:

```
require(stringr)

dat$volume <- ifelse(str_sub(dat$volume, -1) == "M"
                     ,as.numeric(str_sub(dat$volume, 0, nchar(dat$volume)-1))*1000000
                     ,dat$volume)
```